# Use default value updating Sequel model

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I want to do with Sequel something with the effect of:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field = DEFAULT WHERE some_condition;
```

That is, I want to reset a field of an object that already exists on the DB to the default value I set for that column. Perhaps something like `my_object.my_field = :default` (which doesn't work)

Is there a way to do this?

(I'm using MySQL)

Comment: What isn't working with `SET my_field = DEFAULT`?

Comment: `SET my_field = DEFAULT` does work, but I want to do that with the setter of a Sequel::Model object, not with SQL directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to column setters using typecasting, using one is not going to work well.  You can work around it doing `my_object.values[:my_field] = Sequel.lit('DEFAULT')` and then saving, but that's not really recommended except as a last resort (and refresh after updating if you do that).

Assuming that Sequel can parse the default value from the database, you may want to try doing: `my_object.my_field = YourModelClass.db_schema[:my_field][:ruby_default]`

Comment: Using `values[:my_field]` did turn out to be a bit hacky, and it did require a save and refresh to get the object to load the value assigned by the DB.
Since I'm doing this in a method of my model class, I ended up using `self.class.db_schema[:my_field][:ruby_default]`

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the [MySQL Update Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)
and you will note that you can set a columns value to NULL and if that column is set to "NOT NULL" it will be set to its' default value.  This value is not the value you have assigned; instead, it is the default value for the column type (see [Data Type Defaults for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)).

Comment: The column on which I'm interested in doing this does allow `NULL`s, and it also has a default value (the one that gets picked if a value for that column is not specified during an `INSERT`)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
DB[:my_table].where(...).update(:my_field => 'DEFAULT'.lit)
```

The `lit` method puts that in as a literal SQL element without escaping. As far as I know `:default` turns in to a table reference.

Comment: It doesn't work. Eventually it calls the regular setter and typecasting fails

Answer (score 0):

[Jeremay was a bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655267/676874), I can provide a longer example:

Build up testdata:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table(:test){
  column :test, :nvarchar, :size => 5, :default => 'aaaa'
}

DB[:test].insert()
DB[:test].insert( 11 )
DB[:test].each{|data|
  p data
}
```

With `schema`you can determine the Defaults values:

```
DEFAULTS = {}
DB.schema(:test).each{| key, options|
  DEFAULTS[key] = options[:ruby_default]
}

p DEFAULTS
```

Now you can update with defaults:

```
DB[:test].update( :test => DEFAULTS[:test] )

DB[:test].each{|data|
  p data
}
```